# What game is being played on this old TV?

Tags: game-identification

Does anybody know what this game is?

I'm pretty sure it's for the PS2, as that's the only console I owned back then, but I don't know the title.

I apologize for low quality picture, It's a cropped part of a photo taken at my house many years ago (probably around 2005). The TV was in the corner and nothing else in the image was relevant. But maybe somebody could recognize the fonts used and the character?

[image: Unknown Video Game]

Comment: The resolution looks pretty blurry even beyond picture quality; it might be a PS1 game running on the PS2.  Still pretty hard to tell; the fonts are pretty generic, when most kart games were stylized and cartoony, and it's just very hard to tell what character/kart that even is.  Maybe it's a racing mode inside a different game, which would explain the generic quality.

Comment: The closest I can see for era and graphical style is Crash Team Racing but I don't think it is, fonts don't match. I think Rahdil may be right and it's a karting mode within another game.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is Papa Smurf from the game [Smurf Racer](http://smurfs.wikia.com/wiki/Smurf_Racer). [Google Images](https://www.google.de/search?q=complete%20smurf%20racer&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS798US798&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijgJi0qpLcAhVGFywKHcruBsAQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=947) is a link for some solid proof.

[image]

Comment: Played this game in my local McDonald's back when the PlayLand still had a bunch of game systems in it.

Answer (score -4):

Looking at that font, the character on the screen and the gamemode (a race), I'm going to say it's Banjo-Kazooie, however I'm not exactly sure which specific B-K game as I have never actually played it, just seen gameplay.

Here is an image from [Games Revisited](https://gamesrevisited.com/2014/07/17/banjo-kazooie-rare-1998-n64/):
[image]

It's not exact but you can see the bird character is the same (I'm sorry, I don't know his/her name) and the font is similar.

Comment: I don't recall Banjo-Kazooie having a racing mode. Diddy Kong Racing would be the closest but I believe that featured Banjo (the bear) not Kazooie (the bird).

Comment: I'm fairly confident in saying that this is not the game. However, it does bare some resemblance in design from the looks of the picture, and is likely from the same era.

Comment: Banjo Kazooie and Diddy Kong racing were both Rare games and Nintendo only..